# Unable to connect to Mongo DB Atlas using Mule 4 connector

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mulesoft, mule4

I am trying to connect to mongodb Atlas using Mule 4 connector but it is throwing below error.
I am able to connect to the database through MongoDB Compass.

Any help with this?

[image: MongoDb Config]

[image: MongoDb Error]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tested that there is connectivity to the MongoDB server by host and port?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you what do you mean by that? Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: you have to use a command of your operating system to test if you can connect to that host and port from your computer. You might need to install it if not available. For example using telnet `telnet somehost.com 27017`

Comment: How did you solve this? I am also getting this error. 

I can connect to my mongo cloud from Mongo DB compass, but the mule application is not able to connect. 

Is this something related to a firewall? I tried the telnet command it could not connect to my Mongo cloud host.

Comment: Hi, I followed this link and I am able to connect now.

http://dejim.com/connect-to-mongodb-atlas-using-the-mulesoft-mongodb-connector/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue. I could resolve this by upgrading the Mongo DB connector of Mulesoft to version 6.3.0, which takes connection string.

This takes DNS, no need to provide multiple server names & port

[image: Mulesoft connector for Mongo db , version 6.3.0]